# Method of characteristics

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Given the equation
$y^2 u_x + x  u_y = \sin(u^2)$ with
initial condition $u(x,0) = x$,
determine the values of $u_x$, $ u_y$, $u_{xx}$, $u_{yy}$, $u_{xy}$, $u_{yx}$ on the $x$-axis.

I tried the following:
$$\begin{cases}
\frac{dx}{dt} = y^2 \\\\
\frac{dy}{dt} = x \\\\
\frac{dz}{dt} = \sin(z^2)
\end{cases}$$

However, the first two coupled ODEs are really difficult to solve. So I assume there is an easier way to do this.

Comment: @marwalix if you are going to use align, you cant have blank lines between lines and you should use `&`; otherwise, just use the gather environment.

Comment: Ok thanks will do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$\begin{align}
\frac{dx}{dt} &= y^{2} \ \ \ (1)\\
\frac{dy}{dt} &= x \ \ \ \ \ (2)\\\\
(2) \implies \frac{d}{dt} \bigg( \frac{dy}{dt} \bigg) &= \frac{d^{2}y}{dt^{2}} \\
&= \frac{dx}{dt} \\
&= y^{2} \\
&= (1)
\end{align}$$

**EDIT:**

We have

$$y'' = y^{2}$$

Multiply through by $y'$ and integrating

$$\begin{align}
y' y'' &= y' y^{2} \\
\implies \frac{d}{dt} \bigg( \frac{1}{2} y'^{2} \bigg) &= y' y^{2} \\
\implies \frac{1}{2} y'^{2} &= \frac{y^{3}}{3} + C_1 \\
\implies y'^{2} &= \frac{2y^{3}}{3} + C_1 \\
\implies y' &= \pm \sqrt{\frac{2y^{3}}{3} + C_1} \\
\end{align}$$

Separating and integrating

$$\int \frac{dy}{\sqrt{\frac{2y^{3}}{3} + C_1}} = \pm \int dt$$

Can you take it from there?

**EDIT 2:**

From our PDE we have

$$y^{2}u_x + xu_y = \sin(u^{2})$$

Separating into parts, we have

$$\frac{dx}{y^{2}} = \frac{dy}{x} = \frac{du}{\sin(u^{2})}$$

From this we find two equations, take

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{x}{y^{2}} \ \ \ \ \ (*) \\
\frac{du}{dy} = \frac{\sin(u^{2})}{x} \ \ \ \ \ (**)$$

From $(*)$ we find

$$\begin{align}
y^{2}dy &= xdx \\
\implies x &= \sqrt{\frac{2y^{3}}{3} + C_1} \\
\end{align}$$

Hence, using $(**)$ we see

$$\begin{align}
\frac{du}{\sin(u^{2})} &= \frac{dy}{\sqrt{\frac{2y^{3}}{3} + C_1}} \\
\end{align}$$

However, the $u$ integration is ridiculous and can't be done in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: If you are still confused, just comment below this post. Also, could you please accept and upvote my answer to close the question.

Comment: I suppose I am having a brain fart moment but how does one solve y'' = y^2. just separate them out and integrate twice?

Comment: I'll make an edit.

Comment: Oh thank you. That is an interesting trick i forgot all together. Anyway, this seems to be a huge mess. Integrating above will pop another constant. Then using this messy value of y, I'll have to solve for x from dx/dt. Next, solve dz/dt which isn't looking great and then make a switch of variables. So i suppose the question is, is there an easier way to this problem? This method seems like it'll be lot of work.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking that before, it does seem like alot of work. Possibly substitute variables, say set v = y'? Or ansatz a solution? I haven't really looked at the problem in depth because it's late and I'll make mistakes. I'll give it a go in the morning if you're still struggling.

Comment: After looking at the problem, there is a shorter way to do this, but with the same result. I'll make an edit for you.

Comment: Could you also upvote my answer please, just because of the work put in.